# Generate PID from scratchPID

Tags: c, pid

I'm currently on a project **in C** where I need to generate process ID's (PID) for threads so that they can be used for methods such as fork(). I was wondering if there is a known method/process that is used for generating PIDs.

If there isn't, does anyone know a compact way to generate numbers and make sure none get reused?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question well but if you are working with threads in c using pthreads you can use `pthread_self()` in a certain thread to get its PID. Hopes this help, if not please make the question more clear